# Alamofire AFError invalidURL

Tags: swift3, alamofire

Im not able to find where i have gone wrong.I tried all possible solutions but nothing seems to work.
Can anyone suggest where I have gone wrong?
My code is as below:

```
var diaryEntryUrl = "http://myUrl?uid=10001&diary_text=\(textPrint)&location=\(loactionAddrEnc)"
// var diaryEntryUrl = diaryEntryUrlEncode.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) --- tried encoding, but didn't work

let postParameters:[String: Any] = [ "imagesName": self.awsImageArray2, "tagsList": self.tagArray]

    Alamofire.request(diaryEntryUrl, method: .post, parameters: postParameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:]).responseJSON {
        response in
        if response.result.isSuccess{

            print("SuccessFully Added")

        }else{
            print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))")

    }
}
```

I tried encoding the texts also but still error is there.I did it as below:

```
loactionAddrEnc = loactionAddr.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
var textPrint = diaryEntryText.text.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
```

I am getting the follwing error:

[image: error image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the log `Optional` for location and diary text. So it means you need to unwrap it first.

```
if let textPrint = textPrint, let loactionAddrEnc = loactionAddrEnc {
    var diaryEntryUrl = "http://myUrl?uid=10001&diary_text=\(textPrint)&location=\(loactionAddrEnc)"
    // rest of your code
}
```

This should solve your problem. But there is another way.

You can pass all your query params in `postParameters`.

```
var diaryEntryUrl = "http://myUrl"
var postParameters:[String: Any] = [ "imagesName": self.awsImageArray2, "tagsList": self.tagArray]
postParameters["uid"] = "10001"
if let textPrint = textPrint {
    postParameters["diary_text"] = textPrint
}

if let loactionAddrEnc = loactionAddrEnc {
    postParameters["location"] = loactionAddrEnc
}

Alamofire.request(diaryEntryUrl, method: .post, parameters: postParameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:]).responseJSON {
    response in
    if response.result.isSuccess {

        print("SuccessFully Added")

    }else{
        print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))")

}
```